# Replacing NULLs with 'NA' in a SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table similar to this:

```
Value
1,5
2,3
3,0
NULL
4,3
NULL
```

I want to query data and replace NULLs with 'NA' string. However when I try to use CASE:

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN VALUE IS NULL THEN 'NA' ELSE VALUE FROM table;
```

I got error.

How can I replace NULLs with 'NA'?

Comment: You forgot the `END` keyword. You can use `ISNULL` instead of `CASE`

Comment: What error message are you getting? What datatype is column `Value`?

Comment: *"I got error."* And what is that error..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is possibly due to type conversion.  Try:

```
select coalesce(cast(value as varchar(255)), 'N/A')
```

A column/expression can have only one type.  So, if `value` is not a string, then your code tries to convert `'N/A'` to some numeric value.

Comment: Yep. this is type conversion issue

Answer (score 2):

The query is invalid. The `END` keyword is missing from the query. It would be easier to use the `ISNULL` function though :

```
SELECT INULL(VALUE,'NA') AS VALUE 
FROM table
```

With `CASE` the query should be

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN VALUE IS NULL THEN 'NA' 
        ELSE VALUE 
    END AS Value
FROM table
```

If there's only one option, you can use the `IIF` function :

```
SELECT 
     IIF(VALUE IS NULL,'NA',VALUE) AS VALUE
FROM table
```

**Type Conversions**

All branches/options should use the same type or be implicitly convertible to the same type. The question doesn't explain what `VALUE`'s type is, but if it's a numeric field, it will have to be converted into a string, eg :

```
SELECT INULL(CAST(VALUE as varchar(20),'NA') AS VALUE 
FROM table
```